# Where/How do i need to set global variable to be accessed throughout all the models

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have login section when my apps start. So i need to keep trace of the user_id through out the application.

I'm getting the user_id as like below,

```
@@user_id = @params["user_id"]
```

But making it a class variable don't work. As i can't access this from other class or model.

Any way to do this ?

Comment: you can use the global variable $user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this to set it to some global variable which you can initialize in `application.rb` file.

**application.rb**

```
class AppApplication < Rho::RhoApplication

  def initialize

    $user_id ||= ""

  end

end
```

Then on your controller, you can set it to required value.

```
$user_id = @params["user_id"]
```

That's it, now you can access this through out the application.

For details, have a look over here http://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/types-of-variables-in-rhomobile/

Comment: Thanks working great. Just a query, can we access the variable on the view ?

Comment: `This variable can be used in any of the model controller and also can be used in the views also.`